How to translate unicode characters to ISO-8859-15/Latin9 variant?
I have a UTF-8 JSON which contains escaped Unicode characters. For example:
{
    "description": "This is an ellipsis: \u2026"
}

The JSON is parsed with Jackson. At a later stage, the strings are converted into bytes for a ISO-8859-15/Latin9 platform:
final byte[] d = description.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-15"));

Obviously, the ellipsis character (…) is not in the ISO-8859-15/Latin9 character set (see https://www.charset.org/charsets/iso-8859-15).
I am looking for a way to convert non-supported Unicode characters to a sensible ISO-8859-15/Latin9-supported character or set of characters. Here, I would expect three dots.
Examples of other characters which are present in the input and an expected counterpart:
\u2013 -> – -> -
\u2018 -> ‘ -> '
\u2019 -> ’ -> '
\u201c -> “ -> "
\u201d -> ” -> "
\u2022 -> • -> .

Ideally, this is done without having to enumerate all possible inputs and outcomes. That is, not by myself, as I don't want to maintain a rather extensive mapping table.
Is there a JDK class or external library out there which can do the conversion?

Is there a JDK class or external library out there which can do the conversion? Not really. The conversion is highly personal and subjective so there's no way to avoid maintaining your own mappings

Yeah, I figured, that's why I mentioned "sensible". I can live with any sensible mapping, as I long as I don't have to do it myself.

Keep UTF-8 Everywhere…

You might find what you're looking for in java.text.Normalizer.

@k314159, you won't ;) Normalization is not the process of arbitrary codepoint translation. It's for composition/decomposition. It might 'work' in certain very special cases in this context, but only 'by accident'

How will you handle Chinese characters? Emoji? As you see a general way it is impossible. You may just try to normalize with NFC, And then you parse each character, if you can convert to Latin-9 good (note: you can just include the 128 characters not in ASCII for test). Second step you apply to single character NFKD which should be able to give you additional characters. And possibly add a custom translation table on common characters you see on your texts. The rest: put a ?

The real 'solution' has been suggested by @JosefZ

@g00se: not really by accident. compatibility normalization is now, by design, supporting much of such cases (e.g. searched using a limited keyboard).

I’ve been faced with this same task.  There is no universal way to do it.  You will have to create your own mapping of characters.

I'd be inclined to use Transliterator class in icu4j. Target all characters outside the ISO 8859-15 repertoire using the registered transliterators: Any-Latin;Latin-ASCII;, and not transliterate the characters in the ISO 8859-15 repertoire.

Super practical question: why? What are you doing that absolutely requires ISO-8859-15 instead of storing everything in UTF-8 and using a proper presentation layer?

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I can’t speak for Friet, but in my case, the application had to interface with an ancient legacy system that only understood 7-bit ASCII.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't know the OP's reasons, but for some European languages, using UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-15 can increase text size by around 20% which can have an effect, for example, when downloading a large text piece over a slow Internet connection. However, if the original text contains ellipses etc, then ISO-8859-15 is not the right encoding for the text.

to clarify: I can think of many good reasons to need this. I can also think of many bad reasons, so I'm asking like the OP to explain why they need this, not to satisfy my own curiosity but to make sure this post gets edited so that it's clear OP is trying to solve the right problem rather than posting about an XY problem.

This can be done using the Transliteration API of Unicode's ICU  project.
E.g. in Java or Kotlin using gradle, add the correct dependency:
implementation("com.ibm.icu:icu4j:75.1")

then in code, something like this:
val transliterator = Transliterator.getInstance("Latin-ASCII")
val text = transliterator.transliterate(yourTextString)

That should be it. The mappings for the Latin-ASCII transliterator can be found at https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/blob/main/icu4c/source/data/translit/Latin_ASCII.txt if you want to verify if it is sensible enough for your purposes.

You may want to show a full example with the ellipsis in the question and the generated output.

Also note that Java has no val.

Close, but no cigar. The OP explicitly mentioned U+2022 (Bullet) as one of the characters to be converted, but your approach does not provide a mapping for that character.
